# Will this eat up a lot of DB resources? How can I measure preventing issues?

Tags: php, pdo

I am redeveloping my online business. There are a variety of things that I would like to check or update on page load. For example:

```
$db->update('UPDATE staff set status = 2 WHERE expires < '.time());
$db->update('UPDATE loginTokens set status = 2 WHERE expires < '.time());
$db->update('UPDATE matches set status = 2 WHERE expires < '.time());
etc. ( About 10 other updates so far )
```

There is no issue on the code I am just trying to ensure this does not affect load times or load times are minimized.

I am using PDO and I have all of these and more checks/DB updates in the global file of my site. I would like to know if there is a specific way that this should be done. I have read that updates like this should be done when users submit forms so, for example, expire the users' membership when they login etc. But I have various pages that display all premium members for various reasons etc. and I want to keep the entire site is up to date as possible without the potential issue of exhausting DB resources etc. I am wondering if there is a better way to do things, or if there is a way to initiate these updates after the page is loaded so the user does not have to wait until these transactions occur. I also am concerned about specific updates interfering with each other because multiple users are on the site at the same time.

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions without providing any code or other actual information about the system. Such kinds of open ended discussions are not suited for stackoverflow. If you have a *programming problem* then we can help. This assumes there is issue with some code you have written, not open ended "what if".

Comment: @burhanKhalid I have updated the question to include the code, there is nothing wrong with it, i mean it works perfectly fine i am working on the site so i am the only one with access to it, but when we open up the gates and bring over our existing 15k members i don't want the site to hang right out the gate.

Comment: Hmm, if the code is working fine - and you want to optimize it try codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution would to just update the current user in your web request handling and use [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to maintain the database in the background.

This is especially important if you use a SAAS platform with a limited number of web processes.

Comment: The goal is to keep the information as up to date as possible, this is particularly important since even a 10 min delay in db update is crucial, there are many features of the site that NEEDS to stay up to date in real time.

Comment: There will always be a tradeoff, but if you are updating a large amount of database records on every request its going to be painfully slow - and chances are that you are doing it very wrong. 

I would suggest that you do some reading, this question is way to vague for stackoverflow.

Comment: That is the purpose of this question to figure out what the best solution is. I have read around the web and all i could find was creating cronjobs with a milli interval but isn't that the same as what i am doing? I am looking for guidance on the best option.

Comment: Look into pub/sub services and fat client architecture.